# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to pass exch_name to main query in the where clause
but it is giving error

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

Issue 2:

I have passed hard-coded value instead of exch_name for testing purpose
`MV_sum.exch = 'ASX'` but its giving error

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Please guide me on the same....

```
DECLARE
  exch_name     VARCHAR2(200);
  v_exch        VARCHAR2(1000);
  output        VARCHAR2(4000);
  abc           VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_str         VARCHAR2(4000);
  err_code      VARCHAR2 (4000);
  err_msg       VARCHAR2 (4000);

  CURSOR tbl IS
    SELECT DISTINCT MV_sum.exch
      into exch_name
      FROM LLDMA.MERCAUDIT_VOLUME_AGG_SUMMARY MV_sum,
           EXCHANGE_MAPPING ex_map
      WHERE MV_SUM.EXCH = ex_map.agora_exchange
      ORDER BY 1;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (exch_name);

  for x in tbl loop
    EXIT WHEN tbl%NOTFOUND;

   select 'ICTO-10510' ||','|| MV_sum.exch ||','|| 
          to_char(to_date(MV_sum.TRADEDATE, 'yymmdd'), 'dd-Mon-yyyy')  ||
          ','|| '' ||','|| 'TDV' ||','|| MV_sum.new ||','|| "NEW"  ||
          ','|| '' || ','|| ''
     into abc  
     from LLDMA.MERCAUDIT_VOLUME_AGG_SUMMARY MV_sum ,
          EXCHANGE_MAPPING ex_map
     where (TRADEDATE between TO_CHAR  (sysdate-545, 'YYMMDD')
                          and TO_CHAR  (sysdate, 'YYMMDD') ) and
           MV_SUM.EXCH = ex_map.agora_exchange and
           MV_sum.exch = 'ASX' ---Passing hardcoded value for testing
           --and MV_sum.exch = exch_name --If I uncomment this "ORA-01403: no data found"error is coming
     group by MV_sum.exch,
              to_char(to_date(MV_sum.TRADEDATE, 'yymmdd'), 'dd-Mon-yyyy' ),
              MV_sum.new;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE abc into output;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (output);
  end loop;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    err_code := SQLCODE;
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  (err_code || err_msg);
END;
```

Comment: would need to see your data to really be able to help, the messages imply the data is not what you are expecting

Comment: As @davegreen100 said, without knowing what your data is it's difficult to help. A few comments: 1) "NEW" should probably be 'NEW'; 2) you've written `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE abc` but it doesn't look like `abc` will contain a valid SQL statement; 3) you fetch your cursor into a row-variable named `x` but then you don't ever use the results anywhere. I suppose the question which needs to be asked is **what are you trying to accomplish here?**

Comment: Are you sure the query "select 'ICTO-10510' ||','|| MV_sum.exch ||','|| 
          to_char(to_date(MV_sum.TRADEDATE, 'yymmdd'), 'dd-Mon-yyyy')  ||
          ','|| '' ||','|| 'TDV' ||','|| MV_sum.new ||','|| "NEW"  ||
          ','|| '' || ','|| ''
     into abc  ..." always returns one row for each record in your cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a42e9/9. Pay attention how I use cursor: `c.a` not just `c`

Code from the above example:

```
create table t (a int)
;
insert into t values(1)
;
insert into t values(2)
;
create table dbmsoutput (
  pos int,
  mes varchar2(4000)
);
```

```
declare
  b NUMBER(4);
  procedure put_line(p_mes in varchar2) is
     v_pos int; 
  begin  
     select count(0) into v_pos from dbmsoutput;  
     insert into dbmsoutput (pos, mes) values (v_pos, p_mes);
  end;

begin
  for c in (select a from t) loop
    put_line  (c.a);
  end loop;
end;
/

SELECT mes FROM dbmsoutput order by pos
```

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` will not throw either a `no data found` or an `exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` exception. These are purely cursor errors. Per the package comments the only exceptions which `PUT_LINE` can raise are `buffer overflow` and `line length overflow`. Thanks.

Comment: yeah :) you see yourself that the problem is that @ashwini uses `exch_name     VARCHAR2(200)` where he should use corsor `x`. I just cant formulate it in English